# Cannot retrieve Azure AD B2C User Attributes

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to read a custom attribute from Azure AD B2C | User attributes for a user.  If I only ask for userPrincipalName I get that, but userPrincipalName is not in my User Attributes:
[image: User Attributes]

If I try to get one my custom attributes using the `extension_B2CID_ATTRNAME` I get a 400 error.  I've also tried with just `ATTRNAME` and also get a 400 error.  Code below.

How can I read custom user attributes from Azure AD B2C?  Why will it return an attribute that is not in my User Attributes?

```
func GetExtensionForUserId(userId, clientId, tenantId, extensionName, bearerToken string) (string, error) {

    //urlStr := "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/" + tenantId + "/users/" + userId + "?$select=userPrincipalName,extension_" + b2cExtensionsAppId + "_" + extensionName
    //urlStr := "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + userId + "?$select=userPrincipalName,extension_" + b2cExtensionsAppId + "_" + extensionName
    urlStr := "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + userId + "?$select=userPrincipalName,TestAttr"
    fmt.Printf("url: %v\n", urlStr)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", urlStr, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearerToken)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error:  %v\n", err)
        return "", err
    }
    defer func(Body io.ReadCloser) {
        err := Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error from Body.Close(): %v\n", err)
        }
    }(resp.Body)

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        errStr := fmt.Sprintf("Status: %v", resp.Status)
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", errStr)
        return "", errors.New(errStr)
    }

    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        return "", err
    }

    return string(bodyBytes), nil

}
```

Comment: A working C# example - https://github.com/rbrayb/B2CGraphClient-UserManagement-MSAL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `b2cExtensionsAppId` is without the dashes.